# Android-Is it possible to add a clickable link into a string resource

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, android-alertdialog

I usually set up some kind of `AlertDialog` to fire off when a user first uses one of my apps and I explain how to use the app and give an overall introduction to what they just downloaded. I also usually load my strings from a `strings.xml` file.

What I want to do is make one of the words in my string resource clickable like a hyperlink on a web page. Basically you'd have an `AlertDialog` and within the string resource there would be a highlighted word or possibly just a web address that they could press.  I suppose I could just add a button that would take them to the site but I just wanted to know if making a word in your string resource a clickable hyperlink was possible.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Just use an HTML format link in your resource:

`<string name="my_link"><a href="http://somesite.com/">Click me!</a></string>`

You can then use `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` on your `TextView` to make the link clickable.

There is also `TextView`'s `android:autoLink` attribute which should also work.

Comment: Awesome :) Ill try setting this up and post back when I get it to work :)

Comment: I'm finding that everything in the string *after* the link doesn't display (so `<string name="s">This shows and <a href="http://foo.bar/">so does this</a> but this doesn\'t</string>`). How do you do this?

Comment: Actually @andrew, I thought the same since the graphical layout in eclipse clipped the text, but when running on my phone it renders the whole string fine.

Comment: should the attribute be "href", not "ref"?

Comment: can you post the output of your implementation.Liek how does it looks on the GUI?

Comment: android:autoLink="web" works on non-html links on v26 Oreo; but doesn't work on <a></a> tagged links.. setMovementMethod did work..

Answer (score 20):

I found something interesting. Let me know if any of you observed this.

Below hyperlink is not working if you use

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

but works with

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

<string name="my_link">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource">
        Click me!
    </a>
</string>
```

but if you use the following link it works with both

```
android:autoLink="web" (or)
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

<string name="my_link">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource"> 
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource
    </a>
</string>
```

Comment: Use `autoLink="all"`.

Comment: closing </a> after </string>??

Comment: android:linksClickable="true"

Answer (score 10):

As answered by @Nikolay Elenkov In Kotlin I used it from string resources in this way (detailed way for freshers):

in my layout place a checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/termsCB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions" />
```

in strings.xml

```
<string name="terms_and_conditions">I read and accept the <a href="http://www.spiffyshow.com/">Terms and Conditions</a></string>
```

in my `activity` class inside the onCreate() method:

```
termsCB.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, the **hyperlink** always works well, when I:

1. Add these **two** lines to the activity/fragment:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.link)))
```

2. **Do not** add anything to the xml (like autoLink etc).
3. Define link in **strings.xml** like

`<string name="link"><![CDATA[<a href="https://google.com">Google link</a>]]></string>`

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't make strings that contain valid link clickable automatically. What you can do, is add custom view to your dialog and use WebView to show the alert message. In that case, you can store html in your resources and they will be clickable.

```
View alertDialogView = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogWebView);
myWebView.loadData("<a href=\"http://google.com\">Google!</a>", "text/html", "utf-8");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
builder.setView(alertDialogView);
```

alert_dialog_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView android:id="@+id/dialogWebView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the info :) I didnt even think about using a webview thats pretty cool.

Comment: Using a WebView for such a trivial thing is really a bad idea.

Comment: Eduard B., can you elaborate on why that is?