# How I can make links clickable in an AlertDialog without using a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I have this line in the **strings.xml** file:

```
<string name="backup_help_body">Please watch this video if you did not understand the above steps: www.youtube.com</string>
```

and the above text in an **AlertDialog**:

```
AlertDialog.Builder backupHelpDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                backupHelpDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.backup_help_title));
                backupHelpDialog.setMessage(R.string.backup_help_body);
                backupHelpDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.my_notes);
                backupHelpDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface backupHelpDialog, int witch) {
                        // Do Not Do Anything.
                    }
                });

                backupHelpDialog.show();
                return true;
```

How can I make the link clickable in the **AlertDialog** without using a **TextView**?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do without a TextView, I would use a Custom AlertDialog, however you can create a "temporary" TextView within the code to perform what you need, here I leave the url where you have several examples

[How can I get clickable hyperlinks in AlertDialog from a string resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997328/how-can-i-get-clickable-hyperlinks-in-alertdialog-from-a-string-resource)

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML formatting :

Example :

```
<string name="my_link"><a href="http://somesite.com/">Click me!</a></string>
```

For reference :

[Android-Is it possible to add a clickable link into a string resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource)

Now for making the link as clickable, you need to add the LinkMovementMethod to the corresponding Textview.

To get the related Textview, you need to fetch the mAlert field from AlertDialog using reflection and then findviewbyId(android.R.id.alertTitle)

Reference :

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/app/AlertDialog.java#AlertDialog.0mAlert

Comment: Same problem! I can't click on the link.

Comment: I have no any TextView as you can see in my code. I have an ActionBar button, if the user press it, it will shows an AlertDialog. The AlertDialog contains the link which I need to make it clickable.

Comment: @MrGlitch Inside alert dialog, they were using a textview to set the  title. You need to fetch it through reflection. For the time being the easiest way is to go for the custom alert view

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and fastest way (what I do) would be to add a custom layout with a textview inside, then add an onClickListener on that textview.

*#SuperEasyToDo*