# Display link of Youtube from string file - Android

Tags: android

---String file---

```
<string name="childExer">
- Moderate to vigorous activity or vigorous activity:\n\u25CF <a href="https://youtu.be/PHXb_VAVpgY">Running</a>\n \u25CF Swimming \n \u25CF Biking\n \u25CF Jumping Rope
</string>
```

---Java file---

```
private String exercise(String spinnerExercise){

    String recommendationExercise = "";

    if (spinnerChildExercise.equals("30")){
        recommendationExercise = getResources().getString(R.string.childExer);
    }
    return recommendationExercise;
```

I get to display all the activities but the word of "Running" doesn't being a link. I want make it clickable. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746293/android-linkify-textview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android-Is it possible to add a clickable link into a string resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource)

Comment: I have try both of solutions but it still remain the output

Comment: Please edit your question and add the XML of the TextView and the code in the Activity where you set the string to the `TextView`.

Comment: Also, you can try to further track down the issue. Try to directly assign the string as text to the TextView in the XML file like this: `android:text="@string/childExer"` and then add `android:autoLink="all"` and report back whether that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the movement method to the `TextView` that should display the String:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.linkTextView);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

As an alternative, add the `autoLink` attribute to your `TextView` in the XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/linkTextView"
    android:autoLink="all"
    // ...
    />
```

For further reference, please see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204303/android-is-it-possible-to-add-a-clickable-link-into-a-string-resource).

Comment: I have try but the output still same